# What is the reason this code only returns the first row in the array?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm looking to create a 'Drill-Down' UITable for my app.

The user will select `'country' > 'division' > 'team'`.  Each currently exists as a separate table within my database and are linked by id.

I have written a PHP function to get the details of each table and put them in a single array to be sent to swift for use in the UITable.

However, this code currently only outputs:

> {"countries":[{"id":"1","name":"Denmark"}],"divisions":[{"id":"1","country_id":"1","Name":"ALKA SUPERLIGA"}],"teams":[{"id":"1","division_id":"1","name":null}]}

And I would have expected this to retrieve everything

```
    $countries = array();
    $countries = getCountries($countries);

    $divisions = array();
    $divisions = getDivisions($divisions);

    $teams = array();
    $teams = Teams($teams);

    public function getCountries()
        {
        $returnValue = array();
        $sql = "select * from countries";

        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
        if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
            $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            if(!empty($row)){
                $returnValue[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $returnValue;

    }

    public function getDivisions()
    {
        $returnValue = array();
        $sql = "select * from divisions";

        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
        if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
            $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            if(!empty($row)){
                $returnValue[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $returnValue;

    }

    public function getTeams()
    {
        $returnValue = array();
        $sql = "select * from teams";

        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
        if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
            $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            if(!empty($row)){
                $returnValue[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $returnValue;

    }

    echo json_encode(array('countries' => $countries,'divisions' => $divisions,'teams' => $teams));
```

What is the reason it is only printing the first row?

On a secondary note, that null in teams should say 'Brøndby IF' - has it kicked it out because of the special character?

Comment: There should be no problems with "special characters" in string fields, as long as you're getting your character encoding correct all the way through (default advice would be to use UTF-8 all the way through from the front end to the database.) If you can't find the problem, you should raise a separate question for that one.

Comment: I changed the ø to an o directly in the database and it outputted correctly.  I think I will have to raise another question for it as there'll be plenty more where that came from!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually looping through the rows returned from the database. [`fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) fetches a single result row as an array. Try something like:

```
        while ($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          $returnValue[] = $row;
        }
```